# Get the latest date in two different tables and return the corresponding value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the latest date in two different tables and return the corresponding value in excel.

This is what I would want it to be like:

[image]

I'm new at excel so I've just been looking all over the internet for a solution but cant find anything.

Comment: I am not sure what excel version you are using, but if you have access to MS365 then you could try this `=@CHOOSECOLS(SORT(VSTACK(A1:B4,D1:E4),1,-1),2)` or may be this one `=INDEX(SORT(VSTACK(A1:B4,D1:E4),1,-1),1,2)`

Comment: Should I post it as an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Posted an an Answer, as confirmed by OP its working for them:
>
> [image]

---

Try either of the one:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A6`

```
=@CHOOSECOLS(SORT(VSTACK(A1:B4,D1:E4),1,-1),2)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `B6`

```
=INDEX(SORT(VSTACK(A1:B4,D1:E4),1,-1),1,2)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `D6`

```
=TAKE(SORT(VSTACK(A1:B4,D1:E4),1,-1),1,-1)
```

---